# Strange overlapping bug between navigation and status bars when rotating fullscreen videos in iPad

Tags: ipad, rotation, uinavigationbar, fullscreen, statusbar

I'm implementing a video player inside my application and strange things happen when rotating the iPad when the video player is working in full screen.

My test case is kind of easy:

1.- I set orientation to Vertical

2.- I start video playing (non full screen)

3.- I set full screen

4.- I rotate the iPad while in fullscreen and set it to horizontal

5.- I go back to "non full screen"

6.- Navigation and status bar become overlapped overlapped in a very silly way. Look:

[image]

7.- Then I rotate the iPad to Vertical again

Status and Navigation Bars don't overlap anymore. Look again:

[image]

8.- Then I rotate back and forth to Horizontal and Vertical, and everything keeps being OK.

Hints?

I've read some other questions around, but no clear conclusion comes to my mind.
There are some "official" fixes from apple (?) acknowledging some kind of bug, and trying to fix similar situations, like here: [iPad rotation bug when using MPMoviePlayerViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089692/ipad-rotation-bug-when-using-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller/3098341#3098341)

But even implementing that easy solution, the bug still appears for me.
(I don't know if it's a bug, or it might even be a feature (?))

I'll be trying some more messing, but help will be more than welcome.

Greetings

Comment: were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: nope! Sadly no one seems to know any hint about what's happening here...

Comment: It was happening to me because I was hiding both the status bar and nav bar, and when I brought the nav bar back, it still thought the status bar was gone so it moved into its space. How are you initializing your view? If you're doing it programmatically, sometimes I find it best to just do it in viewdidload and set the frame to the application frame, then the app takes care of its resizing itself pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

unhiding status bar BEFORE replacing rootViewController works around this bug

[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden=NO;
self.window.rootViewController = whatever

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MovieSmallScreen) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:MPplayer];

-(void)MovieSmallScreen
{



UIView *view123 = [[UIView alloc] 
                   initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];


self.view.frame=view123.frame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden=YES;

}
```