# NavigationBar under statusbar when comming from landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Im presenting modally a VC, this VC is landscape, and when i dismiss this VC and appears the previous VC (in portrait mode) my navigationBar is under the statusbar.
I stackoverflowed a bit and i found this guy having a similar problem [Strange overlapping bug between navigation and status bars when rotating fullscreen videos in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704203/strange-overlapping-bug-between-navigation-and-status-bars-when-rotating-fullscr) but i tried the solutions mentioned in the comments with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late, but might be helpful to someone coming in search of an answer to this question.
Add constraint for top spacing not to "Top Layout Guide", but to the actual "view". Select view (current distance ...) as shown in screenshot below: 
[image]

Courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24818204/2959346